# Generate List of total sales for similar date from another list that has repeated days

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary, dart

I have a list of daily sales which includes "DateTime" & "Int" for each entry. The issue with this list is that there are some times multiple entries for the same date.

```
final data = [
      DailySales(2022-03-10 05:25:40.000, 200),
      DailySales(2022-03-10 09:10:50.000, 455),
      DailySales(2022-03-09 04:70:30.000, 255),
      DailySales(2022-03-09 20:10:20.000, 525),
      DailySales(2022-02-08 05:60:00.000, 100),
      DailySales(2022-02-10 00:00:00.000, 520),
      DailySales(2022-01-08 12:10:40.000, 100),
      DailySales(2022-01-08 02:30:10.000, 250),
      DailySales(2022-01-10 09:20:00.000, 520),
    ];

class DailySales {
  final DateTime day;
  final int sales;

  DailySales(this.day, this.sales);
}
```

Now Based on the above list, I need to dynamically generate a new list that combine the sales in one entry if there is multiple entries of similar date. i.e one entry per date and the total sales for that date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A basic workaround:**

I'll be implementing a simple technique on the sample data from your question.

Your data:

```
final data = [
    DailySales(2022-03-10 00:00:00.000, 200),
    DailySales(2022-03-10 00:00:00.000, 455),
    DailySales(2022-03-09 00:00:00.000, 255),
    DailySales(2022-03-09 00:00:00.000, 525),
    DailySales(2022-02-08 00:00:00.000, 100),
    DailySales(2022-02-10 00:00:00.000, 520),
    DailySales(2022-01-08 00:00:00.000, 100),
    DailySales(2022-01-08 00:00:00.000, 250),
    DailySales(2022-01-10 00:00:00.000, 520),
];
```

You need to add all the Objects with same date like:

```
void processData() {
  List<DailySales> processedData = [];

  for (var dailySales in data) {
    int sales = 0;

    final dailyFormat = DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(dailySales.day);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

      final dateFromData = DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(data[i].day);

      if (dateFromData == dailyFormat) {
        sales += data[i].sales;
      }
    }

    processedData
        .add(DailySales(DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(dailyFormat), sales));
    
  }
  
  final Map<DateTime, DailySales> map = {
    for (var dailySales in processedData) dailySales.day : dailySales,  
  };
  
  processedData = map.values.toList();
}
```

The list named `processedData` will contain DailySales with one entry for each date.

**Update:** You need to use `intl` package for this.

Comment: Thanks Muhammad. I could not get `sale.day` from ?

Comment: Oops, pardon me, it needs to be dailySales.day, I'll edit it for you. Apologies!

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same number of list including the repeated days. Maybe because the DateTime includes minutes and seconds that differ between days. Is there a solution for that ?

Comment: No it's not because of minutes or seconds difference.. the written code had bug.. wait i will share the correct code in 5 mins

Comment: Sure you may, I'll rewrite the solution for you.

Comment: Thanks Muhammad, but still dose not work. I am getting the same length of list

Comment: Finally I was able to accomplish something. I hope it helps now!

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<data.length;i++){

 if(finalList.contains(data[i].day) {
   final tempSales=finalList.firstWhere((element)=>element.day==data[i].day)
   data[i].sales+= tempSales.sales
  }
   else{
     finalList.add(data);
   }
 
 }
```